# XPS 15 9530: bad sound quality in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, dell, xps

After buying a Dell XPS 15 9530 laptop, I immediately dual-booted it with Ubuntu 23.04. Everything works fine except the sound, which is much worse than in Windows 11. I've searched the internet endlessly for a way to fix this problem, to no avail. It seems to me that the problem is that only the tweeters are detected by the system.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution to improve the sound quality? I've seen several similar complaints without finding a solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can't seem to find a fix anywhere.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed correct - only twitters are detected, not the subwoofers.

**TL:DR;**

Its WIP, but with rebuilt kernel, you can get all 4 speakers working already today, I described latest [here on github issue](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/4624#issuecomment-1845440836). More development and summary can be found on [Discord](https://discord.com/channels/1164868856012079126/1164877701623070770)

**Full breakdown:**

XPS 9500/9510/9520/9530 use x4 speakers, two tweeters connected directly to Realtek audio codec and two woofers (down facing, provide most of the volume) connected to same codec *to same channel* via an amplifier.

Specifically 9530 (subsystem `1028:0beb`) uses Cirrus Logic CS35L41 amplifier, which requires firmware upload to function. This device communicated with laptop via SPI, based on required parameters (that should've been) defined in BIOS's ACPI tables. On Windows, Realtek driver takes care of all of this. On Linux, its a bit of pain:

- Just like 9500/9510/9520 it is required to enable kernel quirk to Realtek codec to connect output of tweeters to input of woofer channel (thus, both left speakers connected to one L channel, same for the right) for system to even acknowledge that there are two more speakers
- It is required to enable SPI module loading for CS35L41 amp, x2 of them, via another kernel quirk

=> these two are combined to one quirk, and were already merged to upstream

- It is required to add missing firmwares for CS35L41 to load, without them it would use default, which yes would make bottom speakers work, but they won't play nice.
- Normally BIOS's ACPI would have device-specific-properties (_DSD) and SPI's chip select gpios for Cirrus Amplifier, but in Dell's case they are simply missing. Its thus required to add .dsl table patch to add _DSD and CS pins, OR kernel patch to add _DSD  and smaller .dsl patch to add CS pins. Potentially in the future, CS pins could also be added to kernel patch, but this has to be supported first

Me and a few more people you would find on Discord server have worked around to find solutions to these problems. Not everything can be taken upstream yet, you can get more info on Github/Discord. For now though, you can apply temporarily patches (github link above, summary of Discord's development) which would make all of the speakers work without delays right away :)

Comment: I followed this discussion on github but was unable to access Discord. I will try to follow the steps now available on the github discussion. I feel that you and others have put a lot of effort into this. Thank you all for that!

Answer (score -1):

XPS's use waves maxxaudio program to enhance the sound, no such thing exists for linux. Linux is essentially useless on these laptops without it.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the main question although it would work OK as a comment.

Comment: @karel The answer is there is no answer, a solution doesn't exist. Many people recommend using an equalizer, but it you want to spend hours trying to get it to sound the same with subpar results, then go ahead.

Comment: I thought this was a driver issue. It seems to have been fixed for other XPS models via kernel patch (see https://github.com/rikvanderkemp/dell-xps-15-9520-audio for example). Also, some discussions indicate that some progress is being made, although no final solution has been published yet (see https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/4624). I hope this is the case...

Comment: @AnCaPeLi It's definitely not fixed on other models as I have a different model and the sound is terrible. Even if it truly is a deeper issue, like I said there is no maxxAudio so your speakers will not sound as good regardless. I have a 7950 and I at least got something to passable my installing EasyEffects and making this preset. Not sure if it will work properly on your pc, but you can download here: https://file.io/VmWgX68wX1qg

Comment: Thanks @tbunreal. I installed EasyEffects but couldn't get the preset you mentioned. The link returned a message saying "The transfer you requested has been deleted. Do you have another way to send this particular preset?

Comment: @AnCaPeLi https://drive.google.com/file/d/15bLpxf28kydcuA1Emu8QKZXYCJAoemVf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @tbunreal, thanks!

Comment: @tbunreal thank you very much!! it sounds quite nice